# AngularJS error :Expected Token '|' is unexpected, expecting [:]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have an condition in my html file where if the device is turned to landscape mode it will automatically need to show some fields in that fields in have used filters but when i run the program i am getting the following code.

```
<tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="ledger in vm.ledgers | orderBy: vm.orderByField : vm.reverseSort" ng-click="vm.gotoLedgerDetail(ledger)">
                <td>{{ ledger.date | formatDate}}</td>
                <td ng-if="vm.orientation === 'landscape'">{{ ledger.transaction_type === "FarmerTrade" ? ledger.bill_no | billtext : ledger.description | isNullAdvance}}</td>
                <td align="right">{{ ledger.amount_in | INR}}</td>
                <td align="right">{{ ledger.amount_out | INR}}</td>
                <td align="right">{{ ledger.other_amount | INR }}</td>
                <td align="right">{{ ledger.balance | INR}}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
```

Error is:

```
vendor.js:13424 Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '|' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 60 of the expression [ledger.transaction_type === "FarmerTrade" ? ledger.bill_no | billtext : ledger.description | isNullAdvance] starting at [| billtext : ledger.description | isNullAdvance].
```

Filter is:

```
.filter('billtext', function () {
return function (data) {
  return 'Bill-No' + ': ' + data.name;
};
```

})

Comment: That's not HTML, it's AngularJS.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code:

```
<tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="ledger in vm.ledgers | orderBy: vm.orderByField : vm.reverseSort" ng-click="vm.gotoLedgerDetail(ledger)">
            <td>{{ ledger.date | formatDate}}</td>
            <td ng-if="vm.orientation === 'landscape'">{{ ledger.transaction_type === "FarmerTrade" ? (ledger.bill_no | billtext) : (ledger.description | isNullAdvance)}}</td>
            <td align="right">{{ ledger.amount_in | INR}}</td>
            <td align="right">{{ ledger.amount_out | INR}}</td>
            <td align="right">{{ ledger.other_amount | INR }}</td>
            <td align="right">{{ ledger.balance | INR}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
```

Check the link also: [Conditional (ternary) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: let me check it out